# Android: How to convert a layout into a drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout, android-drawable

I have a view group which contains an ImageView and a TextView. Is it possible to convert the layout into a drawable and if so what would be the best practice?

This is how my class looks like:

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.tip_loading_layout)
public class SomeClass extends RelativeLayout {


@ViewById(R.id.tip_message_logo)
protected ImageView mImageLogo;

@ViewById(R.id.tip_message)
protected TextView mTipMessage;

Drawable drawable;

public SomeClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SomeClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SomeClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@AfterViews
protected void initAfterViews() {

}

public Drawable getLayoutAsDrawable () {
    this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    this.buildDrawingCache();
    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), this.getDrawingCache(true));
    this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return drawable;
}

public void setmTipMessage (String message) {
    mTipMessage.setText(message);
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is resulting drawable ?

Comment: Why would you like to convert it to a Drawable? It's not for that

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use it in Glide and since the text view must contain different text fro different situation I need it to be drawable.

Comment: you can take a *screenshot* of any view, and use it as `Bitmap`

Comment: @VladMatvienko not good enough

Comment: To use it as an error message.